# PHP script unable to $_GET variable when URL changed via .htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a .htacess file on my wampsever running on my laptop. The below code is in my .htacess file and the page displays okay except that I get get the variables back.

```
RewriteEngine on 

#Request routing 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([0-9]*)$    index.php?ID=$1&Code=$2&v=$3 [nc,qsa] 

# Rewrite for GetSimDate.php?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here 
RewriteRule ^GetSimDate/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*)$ GetSimDate.php?ID=$1&Code=$2 [NC,qsa]
```

In my php file I have tried

`Var_dump($_GET)` and `echo $_GET['ID']` and both are empty

My URL is localhost/myfolder/GetSimDate/1212/hjnef

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options -MultiViews 

# Rewrite for GetSimDate.php?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here 
RewriteRule ^GetSimDate/([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*)$ GetSimDate.php?ID=$1&Code=$2 [NC,QSA,L] 

#Request routing 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)/([a-z0-9_-]*)/([0-9]*)$    index.php?ID=$1&Code=$2&v=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Tried with [NC,QSA,L] and no improvement.

Comment: And you change the order ? What is the problem now? (Test and result)

Comment: I removed all but the GetSimData one, page displays but my var_dump array is still empty.  If I echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] I get GEtSimData.php/12/fud or whatever I enter into my URL

Comment: Add `Options -MultiViews`